# How to show backend response in drop down

Tags: html, angular, database, typescript, api

Currently I'm hardcoding my drop down list options since the backend is not ready and I did it like this

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let notificationType of notificationTypes"
[value]="notificationType.value">{{notificationType.content}}
</mat-option>
```

```
  //I hardcoded like this for now
  notificationTypes = [{ value: 1, content: "Broadcast" }, { value: 2, content: "Alert" }, { value: 3, content: "Release" }];


ngOnInit(): void {

// but now the backend get call for notificationType is ready

   this.notificationService.getNotificationTypes().subscribe((response: any) => {
      console.log("NOTIFICATION TYPES", response);
    })
  }
```

but now the backend get notificationType is ready but I'm not sure how to assign the response values to notificationTypes variables so If I can get any suggestion or help will be really appreciated.

I guess the id = value and content = message.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should wait for the response and assign it. This works:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.notificationService.getNotificationTypes().subscribe((response: any) => {
    this.notificationTypes = response.map(obj => {
       return { value: obj.id, content: obj.message }; 
    };
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    // define the variable which will hold the response    
    notificationTypes = [];    
    
    ngOnInit(): void {    
    
       this.notificationService.getNotificationTypes().subscribe((response: any) => {    
       // assign the response to the defined variable    
          this.notificationTypes = response;    
        });    
      } 

// The binding has to correlate with the response from the server.
// If not, you will get an error

<mat-option *ngFor="let notificationType of notificationTypes"
// It is a common practice for the value to hold the ID of the Item
[value]="notificationType?.id" [matTooltip]="notificationType?.description">{{notificationType?.name}}
</mat-option>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use id as value, name as content and description as tooltip:

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let notificationType of notificationTypes"
[value]="notificationType.id" [matTooltip]="notificationType.description">{{notificationType.name}}
</mat-option>

notificationTypes =[]

      ngOnInit(): void {
          this.notificationService.getNotificationTypes().subscribe((response: any) => {
            this.notificationTypes = response
          });
        }
```